# w3af can not work after all dependencies demanded being installed

Tags: security, web, clickjacking

After I installed all the dependencies in demand, I tried to run

```
./w3af_gui
```

but this error message appeared:

```
The GTK package requirements are not met, please make sure your system meets these requirements:
- PyGTK >= 2.12
- GTK >= 2.12
The required "dot" binary is missing, please install the "graphviz" package in your operating system.
```

For now, I don't know how to proceed. Is there anyone can help, appreciate much.

Comment: Your question is very specific to a linux app. The problem is addressed in this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/issues/987